# Unable to register my bower package - No versions available

Tags: sass, package, bower, bower-install, bower-register

My [bower](http://bower.io/) package **sass-smacss:**
https://github.com/leongaban/sass-smacss

And my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sass-smacss",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "SMACSS based SASS modules for organized style writing",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/leongaban/sass-smacss",
  "main": "sass/main_web.scss",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Leon Gaban",
      "email": "leongaban@gmail.com",
      "homepage": "http://leongaban.com",
      "twitter": "@leongaban"
    }
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/leongaban/sass-smacss.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sass",
    "css",
    "smacss",
    "stylesheets"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "bower.json",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Looks like I was able to bower register it, however when I run `bower info sass-smacss` I get **No versions available**, and it's not found on [Bower's packages search](http://bower.io/search/).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Followed instructions from:
http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/
http://bob.yexley.net/creating-and-maintaining-your-own-bower-package/

---

UPDATE
Thanks [@drorb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097634/drorb) I [added a git tag](http://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). However after registering it again, still getting the No versions available message :(

I did `git tag -a v1.0.0 -m 'First version'`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower package versions are based on Git tags. In your case the sass-smacss Git repository does not contain any tag (only a master branch).
Also notice that tag names (effectively version names) must follow [semver](http://semver.org/) semantics.

Comment: Ah I just added a git tag, thanks for that tip! However still showing No versions available :( and I registered it again. Updated question with git tag info...

Comment: WOOT! :D I see my package on bower! http://bower.io/search/?q=sass-smacss I still don't see a version number when I do bower info sass-smacss, but oh well it's up on bower.io

Comment: @LeonGaban the sass-smacss Github repo still does not contain any tags, this is why no versions are available. Make sure to push whatever tags you created.